# Test class for batch with another class called in it: Batch has 100%, but called class only 24% coverage

Tags: soql, unit-test, code-coverage, map, relationships

Batch class:

```apex
    public class BatchClassForCustomer implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            string query='select id,Name,Contract_Start_Date__c,BIlling_Frequency__c,Recent_Billing_Date__c,LastBillingDate__c,Contract_Expiry_Date__c,CHANNEL_ORDERS__Account__c,Active__c from CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c where BIlling_Frequency__c!=null AND Contract_Start_Date__c!=null AND Active__c=true';
            //System.debug('query'+query);
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c> allCustomerOrderRecords){
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c>customerList=new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c>();
            Id templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = 'License_Expiry_Notification_Template'].id;
            //System.debug('allCustomerOrderRecords'+allCustomerOrderRecords);
            Contact con=[Select Id,Name from Contact limit 1];
            //system.debug('con'+con);
            
            
            
            //List of Adding Customers Before Updating Customer List 
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c> customersForInvoice =new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c>();
            
            
            //Monthly Email Notification and Generate Invoices
            for(CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c customer:allCustomerOrderRecords){
                
                Date  FutureBillingDate=system.today().adddays(1); 
                
                Date  referenceDate=customer.Contract_Start_Date__c;
                
                // Create currentContractStartDatePeriod with monthly Condition
                if(customer.BIlling_Frequency__c=='Monthly'){
                    
                    //System.debug('referenceDate'+referenceDate);
                    
                    Date todayDate = Date.today();
                    //system.debug('todayDate'+todayDate);
                    
                    // calculate the number of month between two dates
                    Integer monthDiff = referenceDate.monthsBetween(todayDate.adddays(1));
                    //system.debug('monthDiff'+monthDiff);
                    
                    //Check conditons is true
                    if ((monthDiff>0 && referenceDate.addMonths(monthDiff) == System.today().adddays(1) && math.mod(monthDiff,1)==0) || (referenceDate == Date.today().addDays(1))) {
                        customersForInvoice.add(customer);
                        //System.debug('B'+(referenceDate.addMonths(monthDiff).day()-1==System.today().day()));
                        //system.debug('B'+(referenceDate == Date.today().addDays(1)));
                        customer.LastBillingDate__c=FutureBillingDate;
                        customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c=FutureBillingDate.addMonths(1);
                        
                        customerList.add(customer);
                        
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage monthlyMail= createEmailMessage(templateId, customer,con);
                        if(monthlyMail!=null){
                            mails.add(monthlyMail);
                        } 
                    }
                    
                }
                
                //Quarterly email Notification 
                if(customer.BIlling_Frequency__c=='Quarterly'){
                    Date todayDate = Date.today();
                    Integer quarterlymonthDiff = referenceDate.monthsBetween(todayDate.adddays(1));
                    
                    //Check conditons is true                
                    if((quarterlymonthDiff>0 && referenceDate.addMonths(quarterlymonthDiff) == System.today().adddays(1) && math.mod(quarterlymonthDiff,3)==0) || (referenceDate == Date.today().addDays(1))){
                        customersForInvoice.add(customer);
                        customer.LastBillingDate__c=FutureBillingDate;
                        customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c=FutureBillingDate.addMonths(3);
                        
                        customerList.add(customer);
                        
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage quarterlyMail= createEmailMessage(templateId, customer,con);
                        if(quarterlyMail!=null){
                            mails.add(quarterlyMail);
                        }
                    }                                         
                    
                }
                
                // Half Yearly Email Notification
                if(customer.BIlling_Frequency__c=='Half Yearly'){
                    Date todayDate = Date.today();
                    Integer halfYearlymonthDiff = referenceDate.monthsBetween(todayDate.adddays(1));
                    
                    
                    if((halfYearlymonthDiff>0 && referenceDate.addMonths(halfYearlymonthDiff) == System.today().adddays(1) && math.mod(halfYearlymonthDiff,6)==0) || (referenceDate == Date.today().addDays(1)) ){
                        customersForInvoice.add(customer);
                        customer.LastBillingDate__c=FutureBillingDate;
                        customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c=FutureBillingDate.addMonths(6);
                        
                        customerList.add(customer);
                        
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage halfYearlyMail= createEmailMessage(templateId, customer,con);
                        if(halfYearlyMail!=null){
                            mails.add(halfYearlyMail);
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                // Annual Email Notification
                if(customer.BIlling_Frequency__c=='Annual'){
                    Date todayDate = Date.today();
                    Integer AnnualmonthDiff = referenceDate.monthsBetween(todayDate.adddays(1));
                    
                    
                    if((AnnualmonthDiff>0 && referenceDate.addMonths(AnnualmonthDiff) == System.today().adddays(1) && math.mod(AnnualmonthDiff,12)==0) || (referenceDate == Date.today().addDays(1))){
                        customersForInvoice.add(customer);
                        customer.LastBillingDate__c=FutureBillingDate;
                        customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c=FutureBillingDate.addMonths(12);
                        
                        customerList.add(customer);
                        
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage AnnualMail= createEmailMessage(templateId, customer,con);
                        if(AnnualMail!=null){
                            mails.add(AnnualMail);
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            if(mails.size() > 0){
                
                //Generate invoices
                //System.debug(customersForInvoice);
                List<Invoice_Item__c> invoices = InvoiceCreationController.generateInvoices(customersForInvoice);
                insert invoices;
                System.debug(invoices);
                List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> invoiceLineItems = InvoiceCreationController.generateInvoiceLineItems(invoices);
                insert invoiceLineItems;
                
                //Update Customer List
                
                update customerList;
                
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            }
        }
        
        //further finish method logic
        
        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
                              TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                              FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =
                              :BC.getJobId()];
            
        }
        
        // Method for Email Notification giving to Contacts via Accounts from customers
        public static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage  createEmailMessage(Id templateId,CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c customer, Contact con){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.toAddresses=new List<String>{'psb@gmail.com'};
                // mail.toAddresses=new List<String>{'piyush@mail.com'};  
                // Who you are sending the email to
                mail.setTargetObjectId(con.id);
            mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            // The email template ID used for the email
            mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
            mail.setWhatId(customer.Id);   
            mail.setBccSender(false);
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
           // mail.setReplyTo('example@gmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('CustomerBillingEmailAlert');
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
            return mail;
        }    
    }
```

InvoiceCreationController Class that is called in Batch class:

```apex
    public class InvoiceCreationController {
        
        public static List<Invoice_Item__c> generateInvoices(List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c> customers) {
            List<Invoice_Item__c> invoices = new List<Invoice_Item__c>();
            Date tomorrow = Date.today().addDays(1);
            
            // Query related Service_Order__c records for all customers in bulk
            Map<Id, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c> serviceOrdersMap = new Map<Id, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c>();
            for (CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c serviceOrder : [SELECT Id, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Status__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c 
                                                                  FROM CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c 
                                                                  WHERE CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c IN :customers]) {
                                                                      if (serviceOrder.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Status__c == 'Provisioned') {
                                                                          serviceOrdersMap.put(serviceOrder.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c, serviceOrder);
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
            
            Integer incrementNumber = 1;
            
            for (CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c customer : customers) {
                // Retrieve the related Service_Order__c record from the map
                CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c serviceOrder = serviceOrdersMap.get(customer.Id);
                
                if (serviceOrder != null) {
                    // Create a new Invoice_Item__c record
                    Invoice_Item__c invoice = new Invoice_Item__c();
                    
                    // Populate invoice details
                    invoice.Customer__c = customer.Id;
                    invoice.Invoice_Start_Date__c = tomorrow;
                    
                    // Set Invoice end date according to customer frequency
                    if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Annual') {
                        invoice.Invoice_End_Date__c = tomorrow.addMonths(12);
                    } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Half Yearly') {
                        invoice.Invoice_End_Date__c = tomorrow.addMonths(6);
                    } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Quarterly') {
                        invoice.Invoice_End_Date__c = tomorrow.addMonths(3);
                    } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Monthly') {
                        invoice.Invoice_End_Date__c = tomorrow.addMonths(1);
                    }
                    
                    // Generate a unique invoice number with date and increment number
                    // Format the increment number with leading zeros
                    String formattedIncrementNumber = String.valueOf(incrementNumber).leftPad(2, '0');
                    String invoiceNumber = 'INV-' + Datetime.now().format('ddMMyy') + '-' + formattedIncrementNumber;
                    
                    invoice.Name = invoiceNumber;
                    invoices.add(invoice);
                    incrementNumber++;
                }
            }
            
            return invoices;
        }
        
        public static List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> generateInvoiceLineItems(List<Invoice_Item__c> invoices) {
            
            // Pre-query customer data and service order details
            
            // Create a map to store customer data like billing frequency, last billing date and next billing date related to invoices
            Map<Id, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c> customerMap = new Map<Id, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c>([
                SELECT Id, LastBillingDate__c, Recent_Billing_Date__c, BIlling_Frequency__c
                FROM CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c
                WHERE Id IN (SELECT Customer__c FROM Invoice_Item__c WHERE Id IN :invoices)
            ]);
            
            // Create a map to store customer as key and list of service order details as values
            Map<Id, List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c>> serviceOrderDetailMap = new Map<Id, List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c>>();
            for (Invoice_Item__c invoice : invoices) {
                serviceOrderDetailMap.put(invoice.Customer__c, new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c>());
            }
            
            // Query service order details related with customer and has service orders picklist field order status as 'Provisioned'.
            //  As customer which are not directly related to service order detail, service order is master of service order details and also has lookup of customer.    
            for (CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sod : [
                SELECT Id, Name, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Quantity__c, RelecoPrice__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Product_Name__r.Name, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Status__c
                FROM CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c
                WHERE CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c IN :customerMap.keySet() AND CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Status__c = 'Provisioned'
            ]) {
                serviceOrderDetailMap.get(sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c).add(sod);
            }
            
            
            List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> invoiceLineItems = new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();
            
            for (Invoice_Item__c invoice : invoices) {
                // Retrieve customer and service order details from maps
                CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c customer = customerMap.get(invoice.Customer__c);
                List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c> serviceOrderDetails = serviceOrderDetailMap.get(invoice.Customer__c);
                
                Integer fullDuration = 0; // Duration based on BIlling_Frequency__c
                
                // Calculate duration based on BIlling_Frequency__c
                if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Annual') {
                    fullDuration = 12;
                } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Half Yearly') {
                    fullDuration = 6;
                } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Quarterly') {
                    fullDuration = 3;
                } else if (customer.BIlling_Frequency__c == 'Monthly') {
                    fullDuration = 1;
                }
                
                // Create a map to store product details for efficient lookup
                Map<String, Invoice_Line_Item__c> productMap = new Map<String, Invoice_Line_Item__c>();
                
                for (CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sod : serviceOrderDetails) {
                    String productName = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Product_Name__r.Name;
                    Decimal productPrice = sod.RelecoPrice__c;
                    Decimal productQuantity = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Quantity__c;
                    
                    // Check if the service start date is in future then skip that Service order details
                    if (sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c > Date.today().adddays(1)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    // Check if the service start date is within the billing date range
                    if (sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c > customer.LastBillingDate__c && sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c < customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c) {
                        
                        Integer daysBetween = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c.daysBetween(customer.Recent_Billing_Date__c);
                        Decimal partialDuration = Decimal.valueOf(daysBetween) / 30.0; // Convert days to a decimal with one decimal place and divide it by 30 
                        partialDuration = partialDuration.setScale(2); // Round the duration to two decimal places
                        
                        String startDate = formatDate(sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Order__r.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Start_Date__c);
                        
                        Invoice_Line_Item__c partialItemEntry = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
                        partialItemEntry.Item_and_Description__c = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Product_Name__r.Name + '(' + startDate + ')';
                        partialItemEntry.Name = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Product_Name__r.Name + '(Partial)';
                        partialItemEntry.Rate__c = sod.RelecoPrice__c;
                        partialItemEntry.Quantity__c = sod.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Quantity__c;
                        partialItemEntry.Duration__c = partialDuration;
                        partialItemEntry.Invoice_Item__c = invoice.Id;
                        invoiceLineItems.add(partialItemEntry);
                    }
                    
                    String productKey = productName + productPrice; // Create a unique key for the product
                    
                    if (productMap.containsKey(productKey)) {
                        // If the product already exists in the map, update its quantity
                        Invoice_Line_Item__c existingItem = productMap.get(productKey);
                        existingItem.Quantity__c += productQuantity;
                    } else {
                        // If the product doesn't exist, create a new entry
                        Invoice_Line_Item__c groupEntry = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
                        groupEntry.Item_and_Description__c = productName;
                        groupEntry.Name = productName;
                        groupEntry.Rate__c = productPrice;
                        groupEntry.Quantity__c = productQuantity;
                        groupEntry.Duration__c = fullDuration;
                        groupEntry.Invoice_Item__c = invoice.Id;
                        productMap.put(productKey, groupEntry); // Store the product in the map for future reference
                    }
                }
                
                // Add the products from the map to the invoiceLineItems list
                invoiceLineItems.addAll(productMap.values());
            }
            
            return invoiceLineItems;
        }
        
        public static String formatDate(Date inputDate) {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(inputDate.year(), inputDate.month(), inputDate.day());
            return dt.format('d MMMM yyyy');
        }
        
        
    }
```

Test Class For Batch:

```apex
    @isTest()
    public class IccTest {
        
        @IsTest
        static void testGenerateInvoices() {
            
            // Create and insert Contract term
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Contract_Terms__c contractTerm=new CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Contract_Terms__c();
            contractTerm.Name='A12.com';
            contractTerm.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_API_Key__c='A12.com';
            contractTerm.CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Contract_Term_External_ID__c='A12.com';
            insert contractTerm;
            
            // Create and Insert products in bulk
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Product_Catalog__c admin = InvoiceDataFactory.createProduct('RelecoHR One Force.com Embedded Admin User Subscription', contractTerm);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Product_Catalog__c manager = InvoiceDataFactory.createProduct('RelecoHR One Force.com Embedded Manager User Subscription', contractTerm);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Product_Catalog__c employee = InvoiceDataFactory.createProduct('RelecoHR One Force.com Embedded Employee User Subscription', contractTerm);
            
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Product_Catalog__c> products = new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Partner_Product_Catalog__c>{admin, manager, employee};
                insert products;
            
            // Create test data for customers and insert in bulk
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c monthlyCustomer = InvoiceDataFactory.createCustomerMonthly();
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c quarterlyCustomer = InvoiceDataFactory.createCustomerQuarterly();
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c halfYearlyCustomer = InvoiceDataFactory.createCustomerForHalfYear();
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c AnnualCustomer = InvoiceDataFactory.createCustomerForAnnual();
            
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c> customers = new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c>{monthlyCustomer, quarterlyCustomer, halfYearlyCustomer, AnnualCustomer};
                insert customers;
            
            // Create test data for Service Orders and insert in bulk
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c som1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId1ForMonthlyCust', system.today().adddays(-13), contractTerm, monthlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c som2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId2ForMonthlyCust', system.today().adddays(-33), contractTerm, monthlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soq1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId1ForQuarterlyCust', system.today().adddays(-30), contractTerm, quarterlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soq2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId2ForQuarterlyCust', system.today().adddays(-99), contractTerm, quarterlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soh1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId1ForHalfYearlyCust', system.today().adddays(-90), contractTerm, halfYearlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soh2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId2ForHalfYearlyCust', system.today().adddays(-200), contractTerm, halfYearlyCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soa1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId1ForAnnualCust', system.today().adddays(-180), contractTerm, AnnualCustomer);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c soa2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrder('cutomerOrgId2ForAnnualCust', system.today().adddays(-390), contractTerm, AnnualCustomer);
            
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c> serviceOrders = new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c>{som1, som2, soq1, soq2, soh1, soh2, soa1, soa2};
                insert serviceOrders;
            
            // Create test data for Service Order Details and insert in bulk
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(10, contractTerm, admin, som1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(5, contractTerm, admin, som1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm3 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(3, contractTerm, employee, som1);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm4 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(10, contractTerm, admin, som2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm5 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(3, contractTerm, manager, som2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodm6 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(2, contractTerm, employee, som2);
            
            // Create and insert Service Order Details for remaining service orders
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(8, contractTerm, admin, soq1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(4, contractTerm, admin, soq1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq3 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(2, contractTerm, employee, soq1);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq4 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(8, contractTerm, admin, soq2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq5 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(4, contractTerm, admin, soq2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodq6 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(2, contractTerm, employee, soq2);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(6, contractTerm, admin, soh1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(3, contractTerm, admin, soh1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh3 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(1, contractTerm, employee, soh1);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh4 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(6, contractTerm, admin, soh2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh5 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(3, contractTerm, admin, soh2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c sodh6 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(1, contractTerm, employee, soh2);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda1 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(4, contractTerm, admin, soa1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda2 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(2, contractTerm, admin, soa1);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda3 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(1, contractTerm, employee, soa1);
            
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda4 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(4, contractTerm, admin, soa2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda5 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(2, contractTerm, admin, soa2);
            CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c soda6 = InvoiceDataFactory.createServiceOrderDetail(1, contractTerm, employee, soa2);
            
            List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c> ServiceOrderDetails = new List<CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c>{
                sodm1, sodm2, sodm3, sodm4, sodm5, sodm6,
                    sodq1, sodq2, sodq3, sodq4, sodq5, sodq6,
                    sodh1, sodh2, sodh3, sodh4, sodh5, sodh6,
                    soda1, soda2, soda3, soda4, soda5, soda6
                    };
                        
            insert ServiceOrderDetails;
            
            
            //Create Account 
            Account acc=new Account();
            acc.Name='RelecoHRSoft';
            insert acc;
            
            
            //Create Contact
            Contact con=new Contact();
            con.LastName='Joy';
            con.Email='example@gmail.com';
            con.AccountId=acc.id;
            insert con; 
            
            Test.startTest();
            
            BatchClassForCustomer b=new BatchClassForCustomer();
            database.executeBatch(b);
            
            Test.stopTest();
            
        }
        
    }
```

I have mainly used the following custom objects: CHANNEL_ORDERS__Customer__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c, CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order_Detail__c, Invoice_Item__c(Invoice) and Invoice_Line_Item__c. Service order is Master of Service order details, invoice and Service order also has lookup field of customer. Invoice is master of invoice line item.
When I run the test, I get 100% coverage of batch class, but batch class also has called InvoiceCreationController class, which only has 24% code coverage. Even when the first if coditions that I have set in  InvoiceCreationController becomes true, the test does not go in that if condition block, hence 75% of code is not covered.

Comment: You should write a separate unit test for the other class anyway. Indeed, ideally you should be able to mock all classes used by a given class to test the target class in isolation (with some tests that are more system tests as well, testing all the classes together, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you, it was a after Inset trigger that I was unaware of which was updating a field value, so problem was solved after updating field value after insert.